# Which is the rotated frame in which the given matrix transforms into this block matrix? [UPDATED]

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

Given a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ b & a & -c \\ c & -c & d \end{pmatrix}$ with positive $a,b,c,d \in R$ , which are the angle $\theta$ and rotation axis that transform $A$ into a matrix of the form $A'=\begin{pmatrix} \beta & \alpha & 0 \\ \alpha & \beta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix}$, with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma > 0$? How can that axis and angle be written in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$?

**UPDATE:** Bellow you can find my solution. Since it has been obtained in a rather heuristic manner, I would like to modify the question and ask for the reasons why, given the symmetry of the matrices involved, those are the rotations and not others. Since I obtained this solution with a lack of rigor, improvements in this regard are welcome.

Comment: Bare problem statements like this one that show no effort of your own look like you’re trying to outsource your homework and are ill-received here. This question will likely be closed without getting an answer. If you’d like to prevent that, read through the [site tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and edit this question to include the information described there.

Comment: I am not a student, and this is not my homework. This is the minimal statement necessary to solve a certain solid mechanics problem. Since this is not a solids mechanics site, I think this is the appropriate way of stating the problem, even if it must be closed without an answer because nobody feels motivated by the problem. But I do.

Comment: Great! Bare problem statements are still discouraged, though. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/265466).

Comment: Are there any other conditions on the entries of $A$? It’s pretty easy to come up with a rotation that puts $a+b$ into the lower right, but that might not be positive. The spectrum of the second matrix is either $+++$ or $++-$, but without more constraints on the original matrix, its spectrum might not match either of these.

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re looking for an orthogonal change of basis, i.e., a rotation matrix $R$ such that $RAR^T$ that produces a matrix of the required form, right?

Comment: Yes. See update.

Comment: How do you know that $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are all positive, as required?

Comment: I define $\lambda_3$ as the largest eigenvalue, and $\lambda_1$ as the smallest. Now, that doesn't mean that they are all positive. We know that positive definite matrices have positive eigenvalues. However, $A$ is not strictly positive due to the $-c$ component. What I do know, is that $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ must be positive due to the physical constraints of the original solid mechanics problem. Therefore, the originally given $a, b, c, d$ values must be such that this constraint is already satisfied.

Comment: Ah. That last bit would’ve been useful information to have.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrices around the axis $z$ and $x$ are

$$R_z(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} cos\theta & -sin\theta & 0 \\ sin\theta & cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$R_x(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & cos\theta & -sin\theta \\ 0 & sin\theta & cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$

Let's denote the eigenvalues of $A$ as $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3$. Since $A$ is real and symmetric, the transformation that diagonalizes $A$ corresponds to a rotation. Let's define

$$ \Lambda = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_1 \end{pmatrix} $$

The rotation $R_z(\pi/4)$ transforms $\Lambda$ into a matrix with the same symmetry as $A'$,

$$ R_z(\pi/4) \Lambda R_z^T(\pi/4)  = \begin{pmatrix} \beta & \alpha & 0 \\ \alpha & \beta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} $$

with

$$ \beta = \frac{\lambda_3+\lambda_2}{2}, \quad \alpha = \frac{\lambda_3-\lambda_2}{2}, \quad \gamma = \lambda_1$$

and therefore

$$ A' = R_z(\pi/4) \Lambda R_z^T(\pi/4)$$

On the other hand, $R_z(\pi/4)R_x(\theta)$ transforms $\Lambda$ into a matrix with the same shape as $A$,

$$ R_z(\pi/4)R_x(\theta) \Lambda R_z^T(\pi/4)R_x^T(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ b & a & -c \\ c & -c & d \end{pmatrix} $$

with

$$ a= \frac{1}{2} \left( \lambda_3 + \lambda_1 sin^2(\theta) + \lambda_2 cos^2(\theta)  \right) \\
b= \frac{1}{2} \left(\lambda_3 -\lambda_1 sin^2(\theta) - \lambda_2 cos^2(\theta) \right) \\
c = \frac{\sqrt 2}{4} (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) sin(2\theta) \\
d = \lambda_1 cos^2(\theta) + \lambda_2 sin^2(\theta)$$

and we can therefore algebraically obtain the expressions for $a, b, c, d$ in terms of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ (or vice versa) since we know their relation with the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$. This relation depends on a single rotation angle around a rotation axis that can be obtained by diagonalizing the transformation matrix $R_{AA'}$ from $A$ to $A'$, which combining the expressions above to eliminate $\Lambda$, corresponds to

$$ R_{AA'} = R_z(\pi/4)R_x(\theta)R_z^T(\pi/4)$$